# Recalling if i woke up to read Fajr prayers

Tags: salat

AsSalam aly kaum

I cannot recall if I woke up to read my fajr prayers. The last I recall was that I was still up at 2.40am (FAJR azaan is at 3.06am) and I went to the bathroom. This is my usual time and I would have gone to offer me ablution. However, I woke up at 6.24am hesitantly trying to understand if I prayed or not.

Please advise me on something as Alhamdullilah I have not intentionally missed any of my prayers since Ramadan finished.

Look forward to your replyrics.

Answer (score -1):

Waalaikumsalam

You will have to re-form your prayers.

The following below translated the quotation of Sheikh Ibn Baz's fatwa for this issue/question:

> When a Muslim is doubtful about performing a specific obligatory Salah,
>   it is obligatory for him to hasten to perform it, because the
>   obligation essentially exists so it should be fulfilled. Thus, it is
>   obligatory for him to hasten to perform it, because the Prophet
>   Muhammad S.A.W says : "Whoever misses a prayer because he sleeps or
>   forgets it should offer it when he remembers it, there is no expiation
>   for it except this." **-Fatawa Ibnu Baz Psrt no. 11, Page No 256.**

Wallahualam.